# Tab bar icon height using react native navigation library

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using react native navigation to start a tab based app, here is the code

```
Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
        tabs: [
            {
                screen: "Starnote.CategoriesActivity",
                title: 'Categories',
                icon: require('../../assets/tabs/cat.png'),
                selectedIcon: require('../../assets/tabs/cat_act.png')
            },
            {
                screen: "Starnote.JobsActivity",
                title: 'Jobs',
                icon: require('../../assets/tabs/job.png'),
                selectedIcon: require('../../assets/tabs/job_act.png')
            },
            {
                screen: "Starnote.FavsActivity",
                title: 'Favourites',
                icon: require('../../assets/tabs/heart.png'),
                selectedIcon: require('../../assets/tabs/heart_act.png')
            },
            {
                screen: "Starnote.SeachActivity",
                title: 'Favourites',
                icon: require('../../assets/tabs/search.png'),
                selectedIcon: require('../../assets/tabs/search_act.png')
            },
            {
                screen: "Starnote.ProfActivity",
                title: 'Favourites',
                icon: require('../../assets/tabs/prof.png'),
                selectedIcon: require('../../assets/tabs/prof_act.png')
            }
        ],
        tabsStyle: {
            tabBarBackgroundColor: '#1f2533',
            tabBarSelectedButtonColor: '#f6a821',
        }
    })
```

The tabs contain the icons but there height is greater then the tab bar, how can i fix this, here is the picture of tab bar created through this code,
[image: tabs at the bottom are coming out of tabbar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -

```
options: {
   bottomTab: {
      fontSize: 12
   }
}
```

add fontSize option